# Write Prepared Statement From Direct Query With Class

Tags: php

I am learning to write prepared statement. I got this online tutorial with class:

```
class DBController {
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $user = "root";
    private $password = "root";
    private $database = "xxxx";
    private $con;

    function __construct() {
        $this->con = $this->connectDB();
    }

    function connectDB() {
        $con = mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->password,$this->database);
        return $con;
    }   


    function runQuery($query) {
        $result = mysqli_query($this->con,$query);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $resultset[] = $row;
        }       
        if(!empty($resultset))
            return $resultset;
    }
```

One of the query from this tutorial is:

```
require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();

$product = $db_handle->runQuery("SELECT item, brand, price, cat FROM product WHERE cat='".$_GET['cat']."'");

$itemArray = array($product[0]['cat']=>array(
'item'=>$product[0]['item'],
'brand'=>$product[0]['brand'],                             
'price'=>$product[0]['price'],                                                                         
'cat'=>$product[0]['cat'],));
```

.......then able to store $itemArray as session variable.

So I try to rewrite it without using class, and with prepared statement like below:

```
$con = new mysqli('localhost','root','root','xxxx');
if ($con->connect_error) {die("error!");}

$sql = $con->prepare("SELECT item, brand, price, cat FROM product WHERE cat=?");
$cat = $_GET['cat'];
$sql->bind_param("s", $cat);
$sql->execute();
$result = $sql->get_result();
$product = $result->fetch_assoc();  

$itemArray = array($product[0]['cat']=>array(
'item'=>$product[0]['item'],
'brand'=>$product[0]['brand'],                             
'price'=>$product[0]['price'],                                                                         
'cat'=>$product[0]['cat'],));
```

Somehow after I rewrite it, I can't store anything to the session variable, now I am stuck. Anyone care to enlighten me where have I done wrong?

Comment: silly question but, is the [session started](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)?

Comment: I expect u at the level that I don't even need to mention to u about "Session Started''

Comment: I'll take that as a yes... One thing I've learned is to make assumptions, even in my own code, those are the kind of things I always check first. I wasn't being condescending here, simply trying to figure out where the problem is to formulate an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$product = $result->fetch_assoc();` try something like this

```
while($product = result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $productset[] = $product;
}

$itemArray = array($productset[0]['cat']=>array(
'item'=>$productset[0]['item'],
'brand'=>$productset[0]['brand'],                             
'price'=>$productset[0]['price'],                                                                         
'cat'=>$productset[0]['cat'],));
```

---

EDIT

So i tried the following, a little edited version of my previous code, with a little dummy db.

```
$sql = $secmysqli->prepare("SELECT item, brand, price, cat FROM product WHERE cat=?");
$cat = $myvar;
$sql->bind_param("s", $cat);
$sql->execute();
$result = $sql->get_result();

while($product = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $productset[] = $product;
    $itemArray = array(
        $product['cat']=>array(
            'item'=>$product['item'],
            'brand'=>$product['brand'],                             
            'price'=>$product['price'],
            'cat'=>$product['cat']
        )
    );
}

session_start();
$_SESSION['item'] = $itemArray;

print_r($_SESSION);
```

i get this result:

```
Array ( [items] => Array ( [1] => Array ( [item] => Golf [brand] => Volkswagen [price] => 38000 [cat] => 1 ) ) [item] => Array ( [1] => Array ( [item] => 320D [brand] => BMW [price] => 49000 [cat] => 1 ) ) )
```

So, i'm not realy shure what the problem is on your end...